# Using SharpAvi to convert images to video

Tags: c#

I'm using SharpAvi .dll to convert a serie of images to video, everything looks fine, but when I try to play the video in windows media player I only get a black screen for one second, nothing else.

This is the code I wrote, (frames is a list of images as base64)

```
private void CreateMovie(List<string> frames)
{
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;
    var framRate = 2;

    var writer = new AviWriter("C:\\test.avi")
    {
        FramesPerSecond = framRate,
        EmitIndex1 = true
    };

    var stream = writer.AddVideoStream();
    stream.Width = width;
    stream.Height = height;
    stream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.DivX;
    stream.BitsPerPixel = BitsPerPixel.Bpp32;

    foreach (var frame in frames)
    {
        byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(frame);
        stream.WriteFrame(true, arr, 0, arr.Length);
    }

    writer.Close();
}
```

I can't see what the error could be. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i've found the errors:

the line:

```
        stream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.DivX;
```

should be:

```
        stream.Codec = KnownFourCCs.Codecs.Uncompressed;
```

and all the frames of the video should be the same size as video, in order to do that i've use this block of code:

```
        foreach (var frame in frames)
        {
            byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(frame);
            var bm = ToBitmap(arr);
            var rbm = ReduceBitmap(bm, 320, 240);

            byte[] fr = BitmapToByteArray(rbm);

            stream.WriteFrame(true, fr, 0, fr.Length);
        }
```

and here the helper functions:

```
    public Bitmap ToBitmap(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        var returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(returnImage);

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap ReduceBitmap(Bitmap original, int reducedWidth, int reducedHeight)
    {
        var reduced = new Bitmap(reducedWidth, reducedHeight);
        using (var dc = Graphics.FromImage(reduced))
        {
            dc.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            dc.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, reducedWidth, reducedHeight), new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return reduced;
    }

    public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapData bmpdata = null;

        try
        {
            bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;
            byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
            IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;

            Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);

            return bytedata;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bmpdata != null)
            {
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
            }
        }
    }
```